# Sitefinity Custom Membership Where Does Updates Carried Out

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, asp.net-membership, sitefinity

I've been wondering regarding [Sitefinity Custom Membership](http://docs.sitefinity.com/custom-membership-provider-full-code). I saw that it does override some base methods for creating user and fetching user. But i can't see how does the update is carried out.

**Edit** (2017-10-02):

Lets say that i retrieved an `Enumerable` of users, contains User A, User B, and User C. I updated User A instance through:

```
 userManagerCustom = UserManager.GetManager("myUserManagerCustom");
 IEnumerable<User> users = userManagerCustom.GetUsers().AsEnumerable();
 User userA = users.First();
 userA.SetUserName("UserA_ch");
 userManagerCustom.SaveChanges()
```

I expect that `userA` be updated. Unfortunately, it is not. Decompiled the source code of `MembershipDataProvider` with no luck as it uses OpenAccess to track changes.

Updates are handled at `CommitTransaction` method. Which is pretty much make things difficult on handling updates on outside sources (e.g. User's provided through RESTApi - well, even creating a custom membership provider backed with EntityFramework also end in crappy implementation).

```
    public override void CommitTransaction()
    {
        this.CollectEventsData();
        base.CommitTransaction();
        this.RaiseEvents(false);
    }
```

Basically, i want a **concrete best practice** to handle updates for Sitefinity Custom Membership provider properly. Asking their support i only got a somewhat useless answer and proceed to close the ticket.

[image: Updates Through Events]

Comment: Are you asking how a user gets updated from the custom source in Sitefinity. Eg. User1 name is Jon it gets updated on the custom system to Jonathan. You want to know where this update happens? Or you made a change in Sitefinity user UI and want the change to persist to the custom storage?

Comment: no, i just implemented a custom membership provider. never i did change the UI whatsover. i'm only curious where does the user data update code is located. it seems it relies on OpenAccess (OA) for tracking changes, and CommitTransaction only throws an event to tell OA that an update is to be saved. Should i dump the decompiled MembershipDataProvider code here? its pretty inconvenient to talk about code without the code..

Comment: I am still having a difficult time understanding your question. Where is this 'update' coming from, where do you expect it to be stored? Is it not being stored where you expect? Do you have error logs? Can you share code via github, gist or some other avenue?

Comment: Hi @JonR, have you checked the link?? The official documentation basically dumps the `MembershipDataProvider`. I have no luxury to put the code in github as i know things through decompiling and Sitefinity is a pretty much closed source.